# How to get all the ranges in Word add In of the Find method

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm making a word plugin using C#. I would like to recreate the word search function by using the Find method of a specific range. The selection should jump to the next found word when clicking ok in the messagebox.

However, my code keeps selecting the last found word in the document?

```
 private void Zoek()
{
  object findText = txtZoek.Text;

  Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

  Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;

  //Word.Application ran = doc.Content.Application;

  Word.Range huidige = doc.Range();

  huidige.Find.Execute(ref findText);

  List<Word.Range> zoekrange = new List<Word.Range>();

 while (huidige.Find.Found)
  {
    //Zoekrange is a global List variabele of Ranges
    zoekrange.Add(huidige);

    huidige.Find.Execute(ref findText);
  }

 Boolean next = true;
  int i = 0;
 while (next)
 {
   zoekrange[i].Select();
   DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Gevonden, volgende?", "Hi", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
   switch (result)
   {
     case DialogResult.OK: { next = true; i++; break; }
     case DialogResult.Cancel: { next = false; break; }
   }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **huidige** is a reference, the instance is updated with every find execution.
So you end up with multiple ranges in your list, all pointing to the same range reference.
This is why you get the last one.

What you need to do is create a copy of the range found and add this range instance to the list.

Hope this helps.

Best regards